# add-migration : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string

Tags: docker, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm running default api core project on Visual studio 2017 with docker support and
I got this error everytime I run the command `add-migration -name name`

> add-migration : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + add-migration
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-Migration], ParameterBindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Add-Migration

PS : This command works without docker support, but return this error when I add docker support

Answer (score 20, accepted):

<strike>It looks like you're hitting issue [#7540](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7540). For now, put your project on a "physical" drive instead of a network file share.</strike> (Scratch that. You're using the PMC commands.)

You're probably hitting issue [#7439](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7439). Make sure your app is selected as the startup project (or use the `-StartupProject` parameter) when running the commands.

Comment: You're totally right, since i add docker support, i have another project "docker-compose" added to my solution, setting my first project as a start up project fixed the problem, thank you @bricelam

Comment: @bricelam Admittedly this will be nit-picky, but now that Docker support is so prominent on the new asp.net project dialog, the decision to make Docker the default project doesn't feel desirable.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many suggested solutions and none seemed to work except for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58592444/1819403

Answer (score 0):

It would be interesting to know with which version of Entity Framework this error occurred.
I had the same error with EF 6.3.0 and I am not using docker at all.

The solution for me was to go back to version 6.2.0 and create the migration with it.