# add-migration : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-applications, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to enable migration in visual studio 2017. When I run it, I'm getting an error. The error message is:

> add-migration : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is
>   null. At line:1 char:1
>   + add-migration ApplyAnnotationsToCustomerName
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-Migration], ParameterBindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Add-Migration.

I tried to uninstalling and reinstall `EntityFramework` and it didn't work.

Also my startup project is set to the project with EF.
nothing worked!!

Comment: Are you sure you are trying to add migration to your EF model?

Comment: Did you run `Enable-Migrations` first?

Comment: @LasseHolm yes i did

Comment: @SoltanAl-khatib have a look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42668775/add-migration-cannot-bind-argument-to-parameter-path-because-it-is-an-empty). It might be the solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ohh... spent hours trying to figure this one out. I tried all the suggestions I could find and even tried what you did uninstalling and reinstalling EF. Nothing seemed to work and it was really frustrating. In the end what ultimately worked for me was how I uninstalled and reinstalled EF!

Uninstall:

```
PM> Uninstall-Package EntityFramework -Force
```

Reinstall EntityFramework:

```
PM> Install-Package EntityFramework -Pre
```

Source: https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/14410987/entity-framework-code-first-migration-error